# How to get the lenght property of a column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with tables and I need to work with inputs from java. For that, I need to know if the input from java can be inserted to the database by not overloading the length of a column. I've tried using `SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('utilizador'),'U_NOME','PRECISION');` but it is giving me an error saying

> SQL Error (1305):FUNCTION bd.COLUMNPROPERTY does not exist

Could some one please help me?

Once again, I'm trying to get the maximum input value that can be inserted to the column, not some that already exists. I just need to know which is the biggest size that I can insert. Per example, if I have a column named U_NOME and its a char with length 30, I want to get the 30, not the lenght of some data that already is in that column.

Thank you.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Error code `1305` looks to be MySQL, which is "function does not exist."

Comment: HeidiSQL 9.4, thats the version

Comment: @SergiyKhomyn HeidiSQL is not a database engine, it's a database client. What is the underlying technology being used as the database engine?

Comment: @esqew It's probably MySQL, as my comment above explains.

Comment: Yes, its MySQL, sorry but I'm only learning

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, Tim. 110% agree with your analysis, but just wanted to make sure we got positive confirmation from OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`COLUMNPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a SQL Server-specific function.

Based on your error code, it appears you're using MySQL, which doesn't implement `COLUMNPROPERTY`. Use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database's `COLUMN` to query the length of the column in question:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = "u_nome"
AND TABLE_NAME = "utilizador"
AND TABLE_SCHEMA="<database_name>"
```

Comment: In fact, the code did look like SQL Server to me +1.  Good detective work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DESCRIBE your_table_here`.  This will give the table column information. 
Examples and details of other options from MySQL are:

1. [Explain / Describe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)
2. [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does `DESCRIBE` print the "maximum input value that can be inserted to the column"?

Comment: Describe provides the table column information only for the specified table.  This is useful as it does not have to do a large down select from the `information_schema.tables`.  The output will for a column that is supposed to store character data will indicate what its size is.  I.e varchar(65) thus meaning it will only store 65 characters.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server you can do the below

```
SELECT Top 1 DATALENGTH(U_NOME) FROM utilizador
```

In MySQl it would be

```
Select LENGTH(U_NOME) FROM utilizador LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Are you sure that any of these two queries returns the "maximum input value" and not the length of any existing row in the table?

Comment: It should be working in the case of datatype CHAR but it won't work with VARCHAR as in CHAR you will always have the specific bytes in the column. Also other shortcoming can be if the value is Null.  You can read about SQL server here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 or for MYSQL here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length. Also it should be ASCII as if it is not than the characters can be more than 1 bytes

Comment: Please explain that further. Assume you have no rows in the database - what would your query return?

Comment: It would not return anything because there is no value in column!

Comment: Yeah, and that is exactly not what the OP asked for: "I'm trying to get the maximum input value that can be inserted to the column, **not some that already exists**"